# ie6 bug, text cropped inside div

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, internet-explorer-6

i have this this simple `div` :

```
<div id="error_message">Some bad things happened here, sorry... try again later!</div>
```

and this `css`:

```
#error_message
{
     width:170px;
     height:44px;
     color:green;
     font-size:15px;
     margin-left:10px;
     text-align:center;
}
```

ok, as i expected `ie6` kicks my butt again :D so what it does is to actually "cut" my text and it displays just "sorry... try again later!"
i google it without any satisfying result. Do you have any antidote for this?

Comment: Drop support for IE6 and encourage your users to move to a modern browser.  Seriously, even Microsoft sent flowers to the IE6 funeral: http://blog.seattlepi.com/microsoft/archives/196608.asp

Comment: i know that..i really know and waited it for a long time... but.. this option isn't available for me :D i have to do it and "stop complaining" :D

Comment: Something else has to be going on in your HTML or CSS. What other rules affect that div? The surrounding area?

Comment: Suggesting dropping support for IE6 is not really helping, considering most IE6 users have been shown to be corporate users who have no control of there browser choice. I agree with dropping support, but the larger websites (i.e. more like Google) need to lead the way, not the little guys...

Comment: Does the rest of the text show up if you try to highlight the area where it should be, or if you scroll the area in and out of view a few times?

Answer (score 0):

Try not setting a height. you don't need it anyway.

Comment: Try making the div very wide ... say, width:300px ... and see if the rest of the text shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the width the problem? 15px is fairly big font size and 170px isn't a lot of room. Try increasing the width (or just removing it). First set 'width: 100%;' to see if that is the problem, then start cutting it back until it fits.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the infamous IE6 disappearing text bug.

http://www.google.com/search?q=ie6+disappearing+text

Historically, the fix is to style a parent div of your problem div with `position:relative`. If it works, you're in luck.

What causes the problem in the first place? One guy says:

> This effect may turn up in a number of different contexts.  We would try to list them here, but the page would become  very long, and make our heads hurt.

-- http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/peekaboo.html

Have fun :)